# Pattern not matching for less or more than 10 numbers

Tags: angular, typescript

I have created a code which matches only more than 10 digits or none,but what if input given is 5 digits?I want to show error if it is less or more than 10 digits.
code :

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="email">Mobile Number</label>
    <input type="number" name="mobileNumber" [(ngModel)]="mobile_no"  ngPattern=" /^[0-9]{10}$/;" class="form-control" id="mobileNumber" minlength="10" maxlength="10" required #mobileNumber="ngModel">
    <div *ngIf="mobileNumber.invalid && (mobileNumber.dirty || mobileNumber.touched)" class="alert alert-danger">
        <div *ngIf="mobileNumber.errors.required || mobileNumber.errors.minlength || mobileNumber.errors.maxlength ||mobileNumber.errors.ngPattern">
        Mobile number is required and it cannot be more than or less than 10 characters. Please enter a valid mobile number.
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can use If else conditions [check this](https://coursetro.com/posts/code/52/Trying-out-the-New-Angular-4-If-Else-Conditionals)

Answer (score 0):

Try to do this:

```
 <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email">Mobile Number</label>
        <input type="number" name="mobileNumber" [(ngModel)]="mobile_no"  ngPattern=" /^[0-9]{10}$/;" class="form-control" id="mobileNumber" minlength="10" maxlength="10" required #mobileNumber="ngModel">
        <div *ngIf="mobileNumber.invalid && (mobileNumber.dirty || mobileNumber.touched)" class="alert alert-danger">
            <div *ngIf="mobileNumber.errors.required || mobileNumber.errors.minlength || mobileNumber.errors.maxlength ||mobileNumber.errors.ngPattern; else #error">
            Mobile number is required and it cannot be more than or less than 10 characters. Please enter a valid mobile number.
            </div>
            <ng-template #error>You should put 10 digits at least</ng-template>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Actually both if else is of same meaning